# how to change the asp.net identity2.0 defaultconnection to the database in azure?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database, asp.net-identity-2

I use visual studio 2015.

At first, I add a new item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model in the model.

Content from a database EF Designer and add a connection.

Data Source is Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient).

Server name is copy the azure server, like this:
[servername].database.windows.net.

Sign in using SQL server verification.

After, I can find my database and conncetion it.

Connection string appears in the Web.confing.

```html
<add name="GoMindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[servername].database.windows.net;initial catalog=[databasename];user id=[user id];password=[user password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I want to use asp.net identity2.0 ,but this way is creat defaultconnection.
like this

```html
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Final-20160725121811.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Final-20160725121811;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And add a table in the database.

But I had a database in the azure server, I want to connection to here.

So I change the connection to this

```html
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=[azure server];Initial Catalog=[database name];User ID=[user id];Password=[user password];MultipleActiveResultSet=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

### when I run the program,an error message appear.

Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the requirements of the current Web. Please review the stack trace for detailed information about the error, and the position generated in the code.

Exception details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

### Original programming errors:

```html
行 153: {
行 154:     var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
行 155:     var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
行 156:     if (result.Succeeded)
行 157:                {
```

Another way I try is copy full GoMindEntities connection string.
like this

```html
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[azure server];initial catalog=[databasename];user id=[user id ];password=[user password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

### I run a program and appear thie message.

ApplicationUser entity type is not part of the current model.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the requirements of the current Web. Please review the stack trace for detailed information about the error, and the position generated in the code.

Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: ApplicationUser not currently part of the entity type content model.

### Original programming errors:

```html
行 153:            {
行 154:                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
行 155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
行 156:                if (result.Succeeded)
行 157:                {
```

I use a mvc program.
I didn't change any code.
Just change the web.config.
So I want to ask how to solve this problem.
Sorry, my English isn't good.....
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `providerName` setting on `DefaultConnection` should stay as `System.Data.SqlClient`. You've currently changed it to `System.Data.EntityClient`, but it's a SQL connection string, not an EF one (with all that metadata stuff in it).